# Querying for no matches in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and am having trouble figuring out how to structure my indices so that I can perform the following query.  I have an index of customers, and an index of customer orders, each of which contain a customer id.  I want to know all the customers for which there are NO orders.  How can I do this?

This is a simplified version of my index mappings:

```
~~~ 
PUT /customers
{
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "customer_id" : {"type": "text"},
            "customer_name" : {"type": "keyword"}
        }
    } 
}

PUT /orders
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "customer_id" : {"type": "text"},
            "customer_name" : {"type": "keyword"},
            "order_id" : {"type": "text"},
            "item" : {"type": "text"},
            "date" : {"type": "date"}
         }
    }
}
```

I understand I want to denormalize my data and so have duplicated the customer name in the orders index, but what I want to know is which customers have no orders over a period of time.

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Sorry!  Version 7.12.

Comment: Can you please share the mappings of index in which customer orders are being stored ? It'll be easier to understand structure of mapping and it'll be easier to provide correct query.

Comment: Yes I added a sample.  Thank you.